# DRUPAL habilitar CLEAN URL

Tags: php, url, url-amigável, drupal

Boa Tarde.

Migrei um website feito em Drupal pra o hostgator e e agora não consigo habilitar a opção de URL Limpa (Clean URL). Alguém pode me dar uma ideia de como arrumar? Provavelmente deve ser alguma configuração no Servidor, mas não sei o que devo solicitar para o suporte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei habilitar direto pelo banco de dados, mas também não funcionou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você acessa a página de URL limpas o Drupal roda um teste para saber se será possível usar esta opção, levando em conta as configurações do servidor. Não é interessante alterar estas opções diretamente no Banco de Dados (na verdade isso nunca é interessante), já que você estará ignorando quaisquer regras do Drupal estabelecidas no PHP. Se a opção de habilitar a URL limpa não estiver ativa, é provável que o servidor não esteja configurado.

Neste caso você precisa pedir que o administrador do sistema habilite o Módulo **rewrite** do Apache. Eles também precisam permitir que o arquivo **.htaccess sobrescreva as configurações do servidor**.

Normalmente o administrador já teria feito isso. Pode ser que o problema seja decorrente de algum cache vindo com a migração. Se o servidor já estiver configurado corretamente, sugiro que você tente limpar o cache.

Neste caso,

1. use a interface padrão do Drupal para desabilitar as URL limpas (/?q=admin/config/ e cliquem em "URL limpas").
2. limpe o cache acessando o endereço http://seusite/update.php.
3. utilize a interface administrativa do Drupal para habilitar as URL limpas novamente. Se neste momento a opção não estiver habilitada, basta solicitar que o administrador faça os passos listados acima.